# Copy row from multiple sheets and delete

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, delete-row

I am new to javascript and scripts in Google. I have been working on a Google Spreadsheet. I need to copy rows from multiple sheets and paste them into a 'closed' sheet and then delete them from the sheet it was found only if in column B the word Cerrado is found. 
When I run the script it only runs on the sheet Material de Papeleria and only is the first row. It will copy and paste if Cerrado is found. 
I would run this script manually. How I can get it to run correctly on all pages and rows?

```
function deleteRow(){
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var tabs = [
      'Mantenimiento',
      'Material de papeleria',
      'Transporte',
      'Recursos para Eventos',
      'Mobiliario',
      'Material de Limpieza (e Higiene)'
    ];
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('closed');

  for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    var sheet=ss.getSheetByName(tabs[i]);
    var range=sheet.getRange('A:AR').getValues();
      if(range[i][1]=='Cerrado')
      {
        sh1.appendRow(range[i]);
        sheet.deleteRow(i+1)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is the code sample you provided missing a line (specifically between `var range...` and `if(range....`)?

Answer (score 1):

You need a nested loop to process the data in `range`. The variable `i` is keeping track of where you are in the `tabs` array. Reusing it when processing the data in `range` doesn't make sense.

Also, you'll want to process the rows in reverse order, otherwise deleting rows as you go will cause the row indexing to mismatch.

```
function deleteRow(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var tabs = [
      'Mantenimiento',
      'Material de papeleria',
      'Transporte',
      'Recursos para Eventos',
      'Mobiliario',
      'Material de Limpieza (e Higiene)'
  ];

  var closedSheet = ss.getSheetByName('closed');

  for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(tabs[i]);
    var range = sheet.getRange('A:AR').getValues();

    for (var j = range.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
      if (range[j][1] == 'Cerrado') {
        sh1.appendRow(range[j]);
        sheet.deleteRow(j+1)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Feel free to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).